# Оповещение о чем-либо на Java

Tags: java, windows

Здравствуйте, сегодня наткнулся на такую проблему: не знаю, как на Java сделать оповещение в винде(как при обновлении java). Насчет иконки и меню в трее знаю, а оповещение так нигде и не нашел

Comment: Оповещение представляет собой окно без декораций с применённым к нему стилем и размещённым контентом. Можно отталкиваться от этого и сгенерировать окошко, всплывающее в правой нижней (чаще всего) части экрана. Реализовать такое решение можно с помощью JavaFX. Близкая задача: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/395831/210827. Если оповещение требуется выводить при каком-то системном событии - надо, чтобы какая-то служба (приложение в фоне, написанное вами) это событие распознавала и вызывала (отображала) оповещение.

Comment: Как-то не очень хороший вариант сгенерировать окошко место оповещения, если вы запустите свой код не на windows, или например на windows будет такая тема оформления, но если сделать типо прямоугольника который находится спррава сверху то сойдет(это можете использовать как идею, которую проще реализовать)

Comment: @DimXenon, Да, можно и так, но насколько я знаю в Java есть отдельная команда, чтобы генерировать оповещение. Могу конечно и ошибаться. Java изучать начал недавно, поэтому, желательно сразу команду

Comment: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/ - всяческие формочки оповещений,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119481/how-to-present-a-simple-alert-message-in-java - речь о JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Сообщение"); и showMessageDialog(null, "сообщение");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080205/popup-message-boxes - вариант для JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю почитать про TrayIcon (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html), а конкретнее - про метод displayMessage.